# Record an SVG animation with MediaRecorder

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple SVG banner and I'm using `animate.css` to fade some layers but MediaRecorder doesn't seem to recognize any type of animation. I've also tried animating it directly within the SVG but that didn't work either.

Is there something I'm missing or what's the easiest way to get some simple fade-ins for SVG layers that work with the recorder so I can export the banners as mp4? I'm open to use any library to animate and record but I have yet to find a simple one that works.

This is my code with a simple SVG and a fade in animation: Animations work, recording works but it doesn't record the fade-in:

```js
let svg = document.querySelector('svg')

svgToVideo.init({
  drawScene: () => svg,
  width: 600,
  height: 500,
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/svg-to-video"></script>

<svg width="300" height="250" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <rect stroke-width="0" id="svg_1" height="346.66667" width="460.66667" y="-50" x="-98.00001" stroke="#000" fill="#111727"/>
  <text class="animate__animated  animate__fadeIn animate__delay-1s 4s" opacity="undefined" transform="matrix(0.426888 0 0 0.426888 34.8669 112.953)" fill="#ffffff" stroke-width="0" x="15.33662" y="-26.5367" id="svg_3" font-size="61" font-family="'Outfit Light'" text-anchor="start" xml:space="preserve" font-style="normal" font-weight="bold" stroke="#000">Lorem ipsum dolor</text>
  <text class="animate__animated  animate__fadeIn animate__delay-1s 4s" opacity="undefined" transform="matrix(0.426888 0 0 0.426888 34.8669 112.953)" fill="#ffffff" stroke-width="0" x="96.94884" y="45.50341" id="svg_2" font-size="61" font-family="'Outfit Light'" text-anchor="start" xml:space="preserve" font-style="normal" font-weight="bold" stroke="#000">sit amet cons</text>
 </g>

 </svg>
```

Comment: See [website](https://superuser.com/questions/48532/convert-animated-svg-to-movie) I think it will solve your problem